# WPF: What would happen List<T> instead of ObservableCollection<T> for data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am experimenting with data binding using this code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace KhoaOOP6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // LOOK AT THIS!!! This is the data; if you use only List the application will break
        ObservableCollection<Student> studentGroup = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
        {
             new Student("Jaakko Laaksonen", "Sammonkatu 5", new DateTime(1995,11,23)),
             new Student("Kaarina Helin", "Tullikatu 7", new DateTime(1970,01,09)),
             new Student("Maria Nyman", "Adlercreutzinkatu   33", new DateTime(1980,02,24)),
             new Student("Liisa Danielsson", "Askolinintie 5", new DateTime(1981,05,26)),
             new Student("Aino Henriksson", "Caloniuksenkatu 12", new DateTime(1971,10,07)),
             new Student("Elsi Gustafsson", "Haukantie 21", new DateTime(1972,11,11)),
             new Student("Henri Mattsson", "Jakarinkatu 18", new DateTime(2003,12,17)),
             new Student("Emili Ojala", "Karhupolku 29", new DateTime(1967,04,30)),
             new Student("Sinikka Jokinen", "Kolavuorenkuja 32", new DateTime(1969,08,15)),
             new Student("Aurora Niemi", "Laamanninpolku 39", new DateTime(1989,09,20))
        };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Do our binding business
            // Create a new binding
            Binding myNewBindDef = new Binding()
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                Source = studentGroup
            };

            // LOOK AT THIS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(studentGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, myNewBindDef);
        }

        private void AddNewBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new Student:
            Student newStudent = new Student(NameTxtBox.Text, AddressTxtBox.Text, DateTime.Parse(DobTxtBox.Text));

            //Add to database
            studentGroup.Add(newStudent);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for now, BUT there are some things I don't understand:

- Problem #1: If I used (List studentGroup) instead of (ObservalbeCollection studentGroup), the UI initially displays the list correctly. However, when I modified the studentGroup list, **the application suddenly crashes**. Why?
- Problem #2: Even weirder than that, the application **only crashed in Release mode**, when I switched to **Debug** mode to track down the error, it doesn't crash. Why? What if I hadn't known beforehand about ObservableCollection, how would I track down bugs like these in the future?

*Edit: Sorry I didn't say this more clearly: Visual Studio did not tell me anything about the exception that occurred, I thought Debugging would do something but it didn't crash so...

Comment: please write exception message

Comment: If the program crashes, it's a problem with the code, not List<T>. Post the exception. Nothing prevents you from using `List<T>` and raising the NotifyPropertyChanged event when it's changed.

Comment: There is no exception message to speak of, it just crashed abruptly. As I tried to debug to see what the exception actually is, however, it did not crash. Which is the reason why I asked and didn't Google the exception in the first place.

Comment: Release and Debug might not get compiled exactly the same, but the former might have some optimizations in its compilation, which sometimes might cause unexpected behavior. However, that Release compilation should be as debuggable as the Debug compilation even without the debugging information to follow the execution in source code. Attach Visual Studio Debug to the Release version of your application and you should catch and be able to examine the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of the point of databinding.  Observables are so-called because they implement INotifyPropertyChanged which either has code associated with it to perform UI updates or the framework you're using does that for you.

A list is not - by default - observable and so there's no plumbing in place to update the UI when the contents of the list change.

Of course, there's absolutely nothing to stop you from implementing a new `List<T>` type which does implement INotifyPropertyChanged except that you're reinventing the wheel since that's exactly what an `ObservableCollection<T>` is.

> Problem #1: If I used (List studentGroup) instead of (ObservalbeCollection studentGroup), the UI initially displays the list correctly. However, when I modified the studentGroup list, the application suddenly crashes. Why?

The UI initially displays the list correctly because it has bound to the static `List<T>` collection.  If you modify the StudentGroup list, the application will crash because the List you bound to no longer exists - rather a modified object exists and has not notified the UI that it is now the binding target.

> Problem #2: Even weirder than that, the application only crashed in Release mode, when I switched to Debug mode to track down the error, it doesn't crash. Why? What if I hadn't known beforehand about ObservableCollection, how would I track down bugs like these in the future

It might not have crashed but I'll be the UI didn't update.  If you hadn't known about ObservableCollection then you would not be qualified to work with WPF databinding.

Comment: Whilst true, sadly it does not answer the question

Comment: @MickyD good thing that it's NOT true. You can have a List<T> *property* and raise the event from its setter, or once your *command* finishes modifying the list. You *don't* need `ObservableCollection` unless you want to update the UI for every modification to the list

Comment: I disagree but will edit to explicitly answer the questions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is true but is not what the question describes.

Comment: @RichBryant the question mentions an exception, without posting it. This has nothing to do with data binding or List. Without the *actual* code and the full exception, it's not possible to say what's wrong

Comment: I know about the implementation of data binding plus I'm not talking about that subject, but the main point is about WHY Visual Studio is showing such a weird behavior that prevents users from knowing what the exception is.